# Test complains about unmocked method

Tags: kotlin, mockk

i am trying to get my first Kotlin unit test running - using MockK. Running the test results in failure.

This is my class to be tested:

```
class Client(private val context: Context) {
    fun sendCommandString(command: String, parameter: String) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intents.ACTION_DATAWEDGE
        intent.putExtra(command, parameter)
        intent.putExtra(Intents.EXTRA_SEND_RESULT, "true")
        context.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}
```

and this is my test:

```
class ClientTest : MockkUnitTest() {
    @RelaxedMockK
    lateinit var context: Context

    @Test
    fun verifySendCommandString() = runTest {
        // Arrange
        every { context.sendBroadcast(any()) } returns Unit
        val client = Client(context)

        // Act
        client.sendCommandString("some command", "some parameter")

        // Assert
        verify(exactly = 1) {
            context.sendBroadcast(withArg {
                Truth.assertThat(it.action).isEqualTo(Intents.ACTION_DATAWEDGE)
                Truth.assertThat(it.extras).isNotNull()
                Truth.assertThat(it.extras!!.containsKey("some command")).isTrue()
                Truth.assertThat(it.getStringExtra("some command")).isEqualTo("some parameter")
                Truth.assertThat(it.extras!!.containsKey(Intents.EXTRA_SEND_RESULT)).isTrue()
                Truth.assertThat(it.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_SEND_RESULT)).isEqualTo("true")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The error is: `Method setAction in android.content.Intent not mocked.`. Well - I know. There should be no need to mock this method. I only have mocked the context to ensure, a correct `intent` has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from slack the reason for this was found. The `Intent` is part of the Android API stub.

First option I tried was to put

```
testOptions {
  unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
}
```

to my `build.gradle.kts`. The exception was gone then - however `Intent()` resulted in being `null`.

I converted the test to be based on the `robolectric` library - which turned out to be the solution. I did not have to mock `Context` anymore but instead collected the sent intents via

```
/* SNIP from my test base class
protected val application: Application by lazy {
  ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<ApplicationStub>()
}
*/

val intents = shadowOf(application).broadcastIntents
```